# How to stay well grounded?

Tags: pcb-design, ground, inductance, ground-loop

After some read about ground plane breaks and inductor loops, now I am totally confused about how to design good PCBs.

I made a small example of a two layer PCB. Blue is the big ground place. Red are top ground copper zones that, for whatever reason, cannot be connected between them on the top plane.

I have this question.

It is a good practice to connect those top zones to the ground plane in one single point?

if I use two points, there will be loops in the top or bottom plane?

Or the loop will happen in the ground plane, even if the top zones are not connected?

This is a picture to describe my questions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where you are coming from so I've tried to answer how I'd do it.

If you need to have several individual components connected to the ground plane (blue) then use individual vias to connect those components to that ground plane. That is usually better practice than having a top localized ground plane.

If you need a top localized ground plane (such as for some SMD chips) then stitch that down to the underside ground plane with several vias.

A top localized plane stitched down to the bottom plane may look like a loop in some respects but it can be argued that it is two ground planes in parallel in that local area.

Vias can be an issue of course - they have inductance and that inductance can make a localized top plane "less strong" than the underside ground plane - this is why several vias (all in parallel) will reduce that inductance.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you connect each part to the master ground plane separately.

**However**, you still want to keep local high frequency currents local and off the main ground plane.  This means a IC and its bypass cap should have their ground pins connected directly together, with one connection to the main ground from that net.  That way the high frequency power currents of the IC flow out the power pin, thru the bypass cap, and back into the IC's ground pin without ever crossing the main ground plane.  If you don't do this, the main ground plane can become a center-fed patch antenna.

This same logic holds for small and well-contain subcircuits.  Switching power supplies can be good examples of this.  You keep the high frequency circulating current local by making a local ground net, then connect this to the main ground in only one place.